what's program data in the `program logs` section of explorers
I have seen this in some program and would love to know the general idea of what it is?
example
Unknown Program (HMDRWmYvL2A9xVKZG8iA1ozxi4gMKiHQz9mFkURKrG4) Instruction
> Program logged: "Instruction: Guess"
> Program invoked: Unknown Program (VRFzZoJdhFWL8rkvu87LpKM3RbcVezpMEc6X5GVDr7y)
  > Program logged: "Instruction: Request"
  > Program invoked: System Program
    > Program returned success
  > Program invoked: System Program
    > Program returned success
  > Program data: N5A4PPBigz2YxtZA/Vx4vWDbQq73fNs96VdBQLHSEILhjYU4xwBOYjfDSQC/GjcggrLsDpYz7jAlT+Gca846HqtFb8UQMM9cAA==
  > Program consumed: 17888 of 187921 compute units
  > Program returned success
> Program consumed: 30371 of 200000 compute units
> Program returned success

what is it and how does one log it out. Is it as expensive(using a lot of CUs) as msg!() macro?

Any output prefixed with Program Data: is using the sol_log_data syscall at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/da029625d180dd1d396d26b74a5c281b7786e8c9/sdk/program/src/log.rs#L116
You can trace down to the syscall's implementation at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/da029625d180dd1d396d26b74a5c281b7786e8c9/programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/logging.rs#L107
Looking at the code, the cost should be much smaller than using msg! because the syscall is charging per byte, and doing the base64 encoding for you, whereas with msg!, you need to do the encoding and string formatting in BPF, which is often extremely costly. For example, just encoding a pubkey to base58 will cost you around 10k CUs in Rust.
